# Changing the font size is automatically reverted in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: text-editors, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Symptom:

1. Open `Tools | Options` window.
2. Select `Environment | Fonts and Colors` section.
3. Change the font size for `Text Editor` from `10` to any other size (eg. `11`)
4. Click `OK` button.
5. After a couple of seconds the font size automatically reverts back to `10` without any interaction.

I tried:

- `devenv.exe /ResetSettings`
- disabling every extension one by one with restarting VS
- deleting all `.vssettings` files from `%MyDocuments%\Visual Studio 2015\Settings`
- deleting all files from `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0` folder

but unfortunately I still cannot change the font size of the text editor. :(

Has anybody met this issue? Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

I removed some registry key settings as well after uninstalling Visual Studio but next time I installed it I ran into this message:

`Project 'xxx' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.`

I tried the uninstall-restart-reinstall-restart way with VS2015 Update 1 a couple times with no success.

Finally I ended up installing VS2015 Update 2. Now it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Try to change any other settings than Fonts, see if the settings will be saved or reverted to the default.

Comment: Are you syncing your environment through a Microsoft Account perhaps?  Disable the syncing and see if your setting changes persist then.

Comment: Disabled syncing but issue still remained.

Comment: I'm on VS2015 Update 3 and I have this issue.  Not quite as described because the font will retain the size I set for a few minutes, perhaps 10 minutes, then revert to the default.  I've actually been looking at the screen when it does it and I can confirm I wasn't touching the mouse or keys at the time.  I also have VS2017, 2019 and 2022 installed (for different customers) and I only have a problem with VS2015; the more recent versions of VS retain the font size I set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem - it doesn't happen on my copy of VS2015, so can only indicate steps which might help :

1. Ensure Visual Studio is updated to Update 2
   (check this in Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio)
2. Ensure your extensions are fully updated
   (check this in Tools -> Extensions and Updates, section Updates)
3. Start Visual Studio in [Safe Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx) (`devenv /SafeMode`)
   This switch prevents all third-party VSPackages from loading when VS starts, thus verifying that the problem is not caused by some installed
   extension.
4. Refresh VS via Control Panel / Programs and Features, right-click, Change, Repair.
5. In the worse case, find an ISO of VS with Update 2 and reinstall.

Comment: I tried safe mode and then tried repair. None of them eliminated the issue. :( I use Update 1 on two PCs with different accounts but this issue occurs only on one of the PCs.

Comment: Well, that leaves reinstallation using the latest ISO.

Comment: Please see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415688/1035334

Answer (score 1):

To change the default font face, size, and colors in Visual Studio 2015:
**1.Select Options from the Tools menu, and in the Environment folder, select Fonts and Colors.
The Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box opens.

2.In Show settings for, select Text Editor.

3.Modify the Font and Size options to change the font face and size for all text elements in all editors.

4.Select the appropriate item in Display items, and then modify the Item foreground and Item background options. 
`Click Use Defaults to reset the default settings.` 
5.Click OK.**

For more [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. :(

Comment: Did you **Click Use Defaults to reset the default settings** before ok it should be **Default settings** to remain

Comment: Yes, I did but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Press "crt" and than "+" and it will make your font text SIZE bigger. If you want to make it smaller press "ctr" and than "-".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this way but I don't want to do it in all the text editor window. I work with lots of files. I'd like to set it globally.

Comment: I will think about that...

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late to answer your question. I also experienced this reverting issue for textbox. However, we just need to select all texts inside the textbox then change the font size using drop-down list. It works for me. Kindly see attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AIKx.jpg).